# Include an extra column from an original table that has an Inner Join that is listing values that only occur in a lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, the first includes a data feed (Data Import) feeding in checkpoints that are clocked on various '**patrols**'. These patrols are linked to '**routes**' (multiple patrols around the same routes). I have the below SQL that ensures that a view is created that results in only the **missed checkpoints** are listed for each patrol conducted. This is working fine, but I need to include the **time from the original table** (data import table) that the checkpoint was clocked. How would I go about ensuring that this time is included in the output view? The field in the original table to be included is **Occurrence Date**, and resides in the **Data Import** Table

Here is my current SQL (working):

```
CREATE VIEW MissedPoints AS
SELECT Routes.[Route id]
     ,[Data Import].[Patrol id]
     ,Routes.[Tag Name]
FROM Routes 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Route Id]
                ,[Patrol ID] 
            from [Data Import]) as [Data Import] 
    on [Data Import].[Route Id] = Routes.[Route Id]
EXCEPT
SELECT [Route Id]
    ,[Patrol ID]
    ,[Tag name]
FROM [Data Import]
```

I just cant seem to get the right SQL in the right place.

Comment: if the checkpoint is missed does it have a time?

Comment: You're actually right, there would be no time clocked as the tag would not have been registered. I did not even realize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you actually want the following. This will give you only the missed checkpoints, assuming that the missed times would be `NULL` if not you can change the where criteria to whatever your missed value is, or put the two lines I marked added into your query in the same place, as well as 1 line in the `except` query to make the fields match up again (But lose the `where` clause).

```
CREATE VIEW MissedPoints AS
SELECT Routes.[Route id]
     ,[Data Import].[Patrol id]
     ,Routes.[Tag Name]
     ,[Data Import].[Occurrence Date]  --Added
FROM Routes 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Route Id]
                ,[Patrol ID] 
                ,[Occurrence Date]  --Added
            from [Data Import]) as [Data Import] 
    on [Data Import].[Route Id] = Routes.[Route Id]
WHERE [Data Import].[Occurrence Date] is NULL
```